# How to add the custom file log in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How can i add the log in file with prestashop 1.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$logger = new FileLogger(0); //0 == debug level, logDebug() won’t work without this.
$logger->setFilename(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/log/debug.log");
$logger->logDebug("message 1");
$logger->logDebug("message 2");
```

Debug messages will look like this (inside "/log/debug.log" at root dir in Prestashop):

*DEBUG* 2018/08/13 – 14:31:48: Hello world

I hope this helps somebody :-). Cheers.